# validation is not working Laravel custom authentication for bcrypted password

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a registration system where password are storing in bycript form. But While I am trying to validate for login purpose, it's saying wrong password . My code for authentication is given bellow :

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $email=$request->post('email');
    $password=$request->post('password');

    $result=Admin::where(['email'=>$email,'password'=>$password])->get();
    if(isset($result['0']->id)){
        $request->session()->put('ADMIN_LOGIN',true);
        $request->session()->put('ADMIN_ID',$result['0']->id);
        return redirect('admin');
    }else{
        $request->session()->flash('error','Please enter valid login details');
        return redirect('admin-login');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to be building your own authentication system, but this would be the flow:

```
use App\Models\Admin;
use Hash;

...

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    ...

    if ($user = Admin::where($request->only('email'))->first()) {
        if (Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password)) {
            // login
        }
    }

    // not authenticated
}
```

You have to find the user by an identifier, so 'email' is used here. You can't query against the password because it is a hash. If you get a user from the query you can then do a hash check on the submitted password and the user's password from the record.

This is a simplified version of what `SessionGuard::attempt`/`Auth::attempt([...])` is doing.

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought, but jetstream and other form of authentication systems looks weird to me (sorry for being like that ) . I have tried your code, now it's showing this error                              "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager::check(), 1 passed in E:\laravel3\Bioscope\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php on line 261 and at least 2 expected"

Comment: that is 2 arguments, copy the code above again ... you don't need to use any starter the SessionGuard comes with Laravel, the auth system exists in the framework, everything else just uses it

Comment: thanks a lot for helping with patience. I really appreciate :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the admin by email like this:

```
$admin = Admin::where(['email'=>$email])->first();
```

and than compare the hashes

```
if ($admin && Hash::check($admin->password, $password)) {
   // ... logged in
} else {
   // ... not legged in
}
```

Comment: it seems more advanced than my level I guess, I did not give the negative feedback though,

Comment: now its saying "Property [password] does not exist on this collection instance.
"

Comment: Oh, sorry, there should be `->first()` not `->get()` method used. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

When your request is processed password comes as plain text while password in your database is hashed.
So you have to **bcrypt** or **hash** your password first to properly make your query.

You can:

```
$password = Hash::make($request->post('password'));
```

Or:

```
$password = bcrypt($request->post('password'));
```

Both Hash and bcrypt helper function work in the same way

Comment: do I need to declare any additional model for that ? I have changed the line by $password=bycript($request->post('password'));   Now it's getting error "Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\bycript()
"

Comment: not bycript but bcrypt and no you don't have to declare it to be able to use helper function.

Comment: sorry for the typo, but I guess if I put bcrypt at this line, it will add some random texts with the given(input) passward , not gonna extract the real passward

Comment: it kept saying "Please enter valid login details"